# FancyBoxapp + Carousel - Having problem in responsiveness and increasing images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, fancybox

I am using Fancyboxapp + Carousel for gallery portfolio. I wanted it adjust the height and responsiveness + add many images in this columns which I couldn't achieve. Have a look in the image [image: here]

Here is my code:

```js
const mainCarousel = new Carousel(document.querySelector("#mainCarousel"), {
  infinite: false,
  Navigation: false,
});
```

```css
.carousel__slide {
    width: 100%;
}
.cpad{
margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="carousel cpad mx-auto" id="mainCarousel">

        <div class="carousel__slide">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/1b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/1.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/2b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/2.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/3b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/3.png" />
                    </a>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/4b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/4.png" />
                    </a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/6b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/6.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/7b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/7.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/8b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/8.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <div class="carousel__slide">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/5.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/6b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/6.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/7b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/7.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/8b.png" data-fancybox="gallery">
                        <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/assets/img/portfolio/website/8.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not possible to give you any answer without seeing a live demo.

Comment: @Janis only i can do this https://jsfiddle.net/o4hj8bmq/4/

Comment: Try smth like this - https://jsfiddle.net/xe1urwkq/

Comment: @Janis https://i.postimg.cc/6Qzq2RM8/image.png look how is my output with your code? why

Comment: Why is what? Too wide? Then set max width using CSS.

Comment: @Janis already set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241866/discussion-between-janis-and-thedebuggger).

Comment: @Janis sure ill ping